# Email getting sent to wrong user

Tags: python, django, email, sendgrid

I have a feature that reschedules donors pickup dates for their donations due to bad weather. The user can do a mass rescheduling. If the donor has an email, it sends them a email that allows them to "Confirm", "Reschedule", or "Cancel" with links that have UUID's in them.

While testing I came across a very strange problem. I mass rescheduled 5 donors, all with emails.

```
austin@gmail.com
another@email.com
metkil@yahoo.com
austin@outlook.com
bbbbb@gmail.com
```

Each email starts with "Hello *DONORS NAME*"...The @yahoo.com email, no matter in what order I put it in, gets the same email as the austin@gmail.com one. Only the @yahoo email do I have this problem. I print out the body of the email right before it gets sent out and the body looks correct but once the email is received, it is wrong and takes the content of the first donor.

I put the process of sending the email in a `for rescheduled_donor in donors_with_emails` loop and sends them out one at a time via sendgrid as my smtp service.

```
  for rescheduled_donor in donors_with_emails

      recipient = rescheduled_donor.email    

      #..........

      body = template.render(context)   
      print 'Recipient: {0}'.format(recipient)     
      email.to = [recipient]                       
      email.body = body                            
      email.attach_alternative(body, "text/html")  
      email.send()                                 
      print email.body
```

The initialization of email is at the top of my method outside of the `for` loop

```
 email = EmailMultiAlternatives()                           
 email.subject = email_script.subject                       
 email.from_email = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL                      
 template = get_template('email/email.html')
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why only this one email is not getting its correct content and receiving the first donors instead.

Comment: You said `for donor in donors` but in example i see `recipient` variable instead. Please update your code with full `for` statement.

Comment: @AndreyNelubin, updated it.

Comment: Okay. It necessary to add the formation of `context` variable and show your template. The problem might be in it.

Comment: @AndreyNelubin, Thanks. Updated it. Very long unfortunately. I don't understand how the context would be an issue since when I print out email.body I can confirm it is printing out the correct body

Comment: Have you tried to initialize `email` in each iteration of `for loop`?

Comment: Just came back to update that was exactly the problem. It worked once I put it all at the end of the loop. I don't understand why that is the problem though. I was changing the value of the body for each donor. Why does the body variable only sometimes get updated?

Comment: I don't now, but if you want to understand I would recommend you to do reverse engineering of EmailMultiAlternatives class. Maybe it caches some parameters or anything else.